# Set of Permutation and Identity Permutation

Tags: permutations

I have a "basic" math question that seems easy but I couldn't figure out.

> Assume I have $L$ = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} and $M$ = set of all
>   permutations on set $L$.
>
> From the description above, I know that the $|L|$ = 10 and $|M|$ = 10!
>
> Now let $J$ = $M$ \ {id} where id is an identity permutation i.e id($x$) = $x$ for all $x$ in $L$.
>
> What is $|J$|?
>   Would it make more sense if I set the value of $x$ first?

Also, X \ Y means set of X "subtract" with set of Y

Comment: It is more likely to get an answer when you show that you have put some effort.

Comment: @mucciolo Hi, I wish I could do such thing. The problem is I don't even understand how to subtract a set with an identity permutation.

Comment: I might be misinterpreting your question, but if $id(x) =x \forall x \in L$ then $M \cap \{id\} = \null$ so $J = M$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misinterpreting your question, but I'm assuming that by $M\{id\}$, you're referring to the quotient space $M/{id}$. If that is the case, we know by Lagrange's theorem that $|M/\{id\}|=|M|/|\{id\}|=10!/1=10!$.
Let me know if I misinterpreted the problem.

Edit: It is just $|J|=10!−1$, as $M$ is the set of permutations and you are taking one away.

Comment: M  \ {id} means that set of M "subtract" by the set of {id}, that's the hint I got.

Comment: Oh, then it is just $|J|=10!-1$, as $M$ is the set of permutations and you are taking one away.

Comment: I'm sorry but where did you get 1? Is {id} always 1?

Comment: Think about it in terms of sizes. $M$ is the set of all permutations and $id \in M$. So when we take out $id$ [which is just a single element of $M$], we are taking away one element of the set.

Comment: I get it now, thanks!